# React / Functional component / Conditional render on callback / Not Working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-rendering

Why this does not work ?

```
import React from 'react';

function Room() {
    let check = null;

    const ibegyouwork = () => {
        check = <button>New button</button>;
    } 

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={ibegyouwork}>Display my button now !!!!</button>    
            {check}
        </div>
    );
}

export default Room;
```

And this works fine ?

import React from 'react';

```
function Room() {
    let check = null;

    return (
        <div>
            <button>No need for this button because in this case the second button is auto-displayed</button>    
            {check}
        </div>
    );
}

export default Room;
```

Basically I try to render a component based on a condition. This is a very basic example. But what I have is very similar. If you wonder why I need to update the check variable inside that function is because in my example I have a callback function there where I receive an ID which I need to use in that new component.

The example that I provided to you is basically a button and I want to show another one when I press on this one.
I am new to React and despite I searched in the past 2 hours for a solution I couldn't find anything to address this issue.

Any tips are highly appreciated !

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html ;)

Comment: Using state is the core mechanism of React :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your component has no idea that something has changed when you click the button. You will need to use [state](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) in order to inform React that a rerender is required:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'

function Room() {
    const [check, setCheck] = useState(null);

    const ibegyouwork = () => {
        setCheck(<button>New button</button>);
    } 

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={ibegyouwork}>Display my button now !!!!</button>
            {check}
        </div>
    );
}

export default Room;
```

When you call `setCheck`, React basically decides that a rerender is required, and updates the view.

Answer (score 1):

The latter is working because there are no changes to the `check` value that should appear on the DOM.
If `check` changes should impact and trigger the React render function, you would want to use a state for show/hide condition.

```
import React from 'react';

const Check = () => <button>New button</button>;

function Room() {
    const [show, setShow] = React.useState(false);

    const ibegyouwork = () => {
        setShow(true);
    } 

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={ibegyouwork}>Display my button now !!!!</button>    
            {show && <Check />}
        </div>
    );
}

export default Room;
```